# error header(location)

Tags: mysql, html5, php7, php5

index.php donde puedo manipular las vistas tengo este tipo de error
**Cannot modify header information - headers already sent Este es el error: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ()**

```
<?php
//se utiliza para asociar toda la variables de session con todo los archivos que esta en el archivo index
session_start();
//autocarga de los archivos controladores que contienens la clase y el metodo a utilizar
require_once 'autoload.php';
//conexion con base de datos my tienda
require_once 'confg/basedatos.php';
//define un trozo de la url como estatica y sino no carga un controlador carga otro por default.
require_once 'confg/parametros.php';
//utilidades
require_once 'helper/utility.php';
//visitas de header y formroles
require_once 'views/diseño/header.php';
require_once 'views/diseño/formroles.php';

//function de error
function show_error(){
    $error = new errorController();
    $error->errorcontraladormetodo();
}

if(isset($_GET['controller'])){
    //para obtener nombre del controlardo = el nombre de la clase junto ala palabra concatenada Controller
    $nombre_controlador = $_GET['controller'].'Controller';
}elseif(!isset($_GET['controller']) && !isset($_GET['action'])){
    //cuando no existe el controlador y el metodo coloca por default 
    //un contorlador ---- cong/parametro.php
    $nombre_controlador = controller_default;   
}else{
    show_error();
    exit();
}

// si existe la clase de controller. 
if(class_exists($nombre_controlador)){  
//crear un objeto o instancia con la clase exitente
    $controlador = new $nombre_controlador();
    //si existe el metodo en la clase solicitada
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && method_exists($controlador, $_GET['action'])){
        //almacenar el metodo 
        $action = $_GET['action'];
        //con la instacia llama el metodo que se creo
        $controlador->$action();
    }elseif(!isset($_GET['controller']) && !isset($_GET['action'])){
        //cuando no existe el controlador y el metodo coloca por default 
        //un contorlador ---- cong/parametro.php 
        $action_default = action_default;
        $controlador->$action_default();
    }else{
        show_error();
    }
}else{
    show_error();
}

//vista footer
require_once 'views/diseño/footer.php';
```

**1. vista** --- (realizar un login)cuando coloco los datos en el formularion el correo y la contraseña que esta ya existen en la database y le doy click en ingresar me aparece el error como este ** **Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent byo_**
** --- y me señala que se origina el error en en el link

usuario/cerrarsesion">cerrar sesion

```
    <!--menu principal-->
<div class="col-lg-4">

<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['identity'])): ?>
   <div class="texto">
      <h3 class="login">Loging</h3>
   </div>
   <form action="<?=base_url?>usuario/ingresar" method="POST" class="espacio">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
            <label for="user">Usuario</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control is-valid" name="email" value="" required />
            <div class="valid-feedback">
               looks good!
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-lg-12 ">
            <label for="pass">Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control is-valid" name="pass" value="" required />
            <div class="valid-feedback">
               Looks good!
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary espacio">Ingresar</button>

   </form>
<?php else: ?>
   <h3><?=$_SESSION['identity']->nombre?> <?=$_SESSION['identity']->apellidos?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>

   <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="link_aside">
         <ul class="fa-ul">
            <li><a href=""><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i></span>Mis pedidos</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-id-badge"></i></span>Gestionar categorias</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i></span>Gestionar pedidos</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?=base_url?>usuario/cerrarsesion">cerrar sesion</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<!--pedidos y articulos-->
<div class="col-lg-8">
```

**2.vista siguiente que le sigue ala primera vista**

```
<h1 class="titulo espacio1 text-center">Pedidos</h1>

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around">

   <div class="card border border-success producto">
      <img src="<?=base_url?>isset/camiseta.png" class="card-img-top div_img" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">Camiseta</h5>
         <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
            card's content.</p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Comprar</a>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="card border border-danger producto">
      <img src="<?=base_url?>isset/camiseta.png" class="card-img-top div_img" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">Camiseta</h5>
         <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
            card's content.</p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Comprar</a>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="card border border-info producto">
      <img src="<?=base_url?>isset/camiseta.png" class=" card-img-top div_img" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">Camiseta</h5>
         <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
            card's content.</p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Comprar</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**3. modelo** -- este es el controlador con la ** clase que contiene el metodo de ingresar donde tiene el header(location) donde me señala tambien que tengo el error**

```
<?php
//archivo de modelo usuarios.php en donde se les envia los metodos ala class usuario
require_once 'modelo/usuarios.php';

class usuarioController {

   public function registro(){
    //renderiza la vista de registro.php 
    require_once "views/usuario/registro.php";
   }

   public function guardar(){
     //metodo para guardar datos en la database mytienda
      if(isset($_POST)){

        $nombre = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : false;
        $apellidos = isset($_POST['lname']) ? $_POST['lname'] : false;
        $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
        $password = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : false;

        if($nombre && $apellidos && $email && $password){
              //instancia o objeto creado con la clase usuario del archivo modelo/usuarios.php
              $usuario = new usuario();
              //ntancias creada con los metodos de la clase usuario del archivo modelo/usuarios.php
              $usuario->setnombre($nombre);
              $usuario->setapellido($apellidos);
              $usuario->setcorreo($email);
              $usuario->setcontraseña($password);

              //la instacia guardar() regresa true si la database inserto los datos luego lo alacena en la variable $save
              $save = $usuario->guardar();
            
              if($save){        
                // se crea estas variables de seccion       
                $_SESSION['register'] = "complete";
              }else{
                $_SESSION['register'] = "failed1";
              }
        }else{
                $_SESSION['register'] = "failed";
              }
      }else{
        $_SESSION['register'] = "failed2";
      }
     //te redirecciona ala controlador usuario/registro que contiene la vista registro.php
    header("Location:".base_url.'usuario/registro');
    exit();
  }

  public function ingresar(){

      if(isset($_POST)){
        // Identificar al usuario
        // Consulta a la base de datos
        $usuario = new usuario();
        $usuario->setcorreo($_POST['email']);
        $usuario->setcontraseña($_POST['pass']);
        
        $identity = $usuario->registrate();

        //var_dump($identity);
        //die();
        
        if($identity && is_object($identity)){
          $_SESSION['identity'] = $identity;
          
          if($identity->rol == 'admin'){
            $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
          }
          
        }else{
          $_SESSION['error_login'] = 'Identificación fallida !!';
        }
      
      }
    header("Location:".base_url);
  }

  public function cerrarsesion(){
      if(isset($_SESSION['identity'])){
        unset($_SESSION['identity']);
      }
      
      if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
        unset($_SESSION['admin']);
      }
        header("Location:".base_url);
    }

}
```

** con respecto ala conexion de la base de dato todo lo hace bien **

Comment: Probablemente sea porque tenés algún espacio en blanco antes de la apertura de PHP `<?php` en el archivo donde hacés el `session_start();`.

Answer (score 0):

Puede deberse a que existen espacios en blanco o algún otro tipo de carácter, ese puede ser un problema, otro tal vez que todos los require_once los ubiques al inicio y luego las funciones o métodos y código en general.